# Replace formula value and blank in cells of a column with zero

Tags: excel, vba

I want a vba code which will prompt to input the column name, and after being provided with a column name it will replace all the cells in the column those have any formula  or are blank with zero and leave rest of cells of the column as it is.

Comment: New to vba so tried to solve by looking up code from here and there but didn't work.So nothing much here at my end.

Comment: @gautam You have to post the code you have tried, so that its easy to suggest/provide a solution for those who are looking on to this. Please read this documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the latest version.

1. it only runs between `FirstRow` and `LastRow`
2. if the formula contains `DATE()` or `TODAY()` it is not zeroed.

The code:

```
    Sub PatchColumn_3()
        Dim FirstRow As String, LastRow As String
        Dim rng As Range, Cell As Range, v As String
        Dim s As String, FormulaCells As Range, BlankCells As Range
        
        FirstRow = "2"
        LastRow = "636"
        
        s = Application.InputBox(prompt:="enter column ID:", Type:=2)
        Set rng = Range(s & FirstRow & ":" & s & LastRow)
        
        On Error Resume Next
            Set FormulaCells = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            Set BlankCells = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not FormulaCells Is Nothing Then
            For Each Cell In FormulaCells
                v = Cell.Formula
                If InStr(v, "TODAY") = 0 And InStr(v, "DATE") = 0 Then Cell.Value = 0
            Next Cell
        End If
        
        If Not BlankCells Is Nothing Then BlankCells.Value = 0
     End Sub
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your support. Just got two ideas 1) what if I can provide the row range so that it will perform the operation on certain needed part of sheet rather than whole sheet it will save time. 2) Instead of replacing the cell value with zero it will delete the row. Also got a error 13 type mismatch

Comment: @gautam - To delete the entire row, you only need to replace the `r.Value = 0` with `r.EntireRow.Delete`. But you will have to loop from the bottom or the code will skip rows. It would probable be faster if you use `AutoFilter` and delete the visible data.

Comment: Thanks Gmalc. Observed few more things in my sheet. Can I do it like, delete the row or replace with zero if any other formula other than date formula is in the cell. Thanks to all for their support

Comment: @gautam  To improve the **speed** of the macro, see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked really fast. In some cells there are date formula that need to be left as it is .also can there be a option which will force the vba to run between certain row numbers e.g between row 2 to row 636.Thanks again

Comment: @gautam do you want the row numbers **fixed** ??

Comment: @gautam  See **Updates**

Comment: hey Gary's Student thanks u r an angel man.  v = Cell.Formula
                If InStr(v, "TODAY") = 0 And InStr(v, "DATE") = 0 Then Cell.Value = 0 What will this do ? is it to exclude the Date formula in cell from replacing with zero or will it cell containing date formula with zero. What I need is if the cell contain the date formula then it should leave the cell as it and if there is a blank or any other formula then replace with zero. Can a input screen be provided for row range also.

Comment: @Gary's Student I want the row number to be variable. Just like column, a input screen for row numbers. 2nd thing I need is if the cell contains a date formula, it should leave at is and if any other formula then replace with a zero.

Comment: @Gary's Student just one more trouble in data validation. I feel embarrassed but as I run validation it throws some thing new. If the data in the cells in column is in,DD-MMM-YY(e.g 29-JAN-16) format (due to formula in the cell or due typed data) it should stay as it is else should get replaced by zero or  the whole row should get deleted.I hope u understand.Thanks for your help.